# Wordpress, conditional widgets display

Tags: wordpress, widget

I need to display a widget only on posts that contains XYZ in title.
e.g.
title xyz title – widget is showing
title title – widget is not showing

I'm using widget logic, but in this case it is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution: Write custom code in your functions.php and create a shortcode, just put that shortcode in your widget area and call that widget. it will work.